# Canvas.GetTop not updated after Element drag

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a Rectangle nested within a `Canvas`. The rectangle has a `MouseDragElementBehavior` attached to it, so it can move freely in the canvas.

I need to calculate the position of the rectangle after each drag. The problem is that the

```
Canvas.GetTop(rectangle1)
```

only works for the first time, i.e. before the rectangle is dragged. After the drag, the method call returns the initial position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those behaviors usually work by applying a [`RenderTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx), if it uses a [`TranslateTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.aspx) you can get the offset value from that and add it to the canvas position.

Alternatively you might just want to implement your own dragging logic.